# Websocket on dreamhost shared hosting

Tags: shared-hosting, dreamhost, socket

I would like to build a small webapp with some i/o communication with the server via ajax.

Since I'm on a dreamhost shared server I already know that I cannot use node.js to build my app. But now, reading around the internet, I'm starting to suspect that I can also forget about websockets!!!

Am i right??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-137233.html) you have to upgrade your DH server from shared to VPS or Dedicated to use WebSocket.

Comment: yep, discovered already :/

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your host.  Only they can answer your question.